# How to isolate API data in Android ui tests?

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am trying to add UI testing to my app using Espresso and so far I got a few simple tests to pass. The issue I'm facing however is that most my app - like many others out there - depends heavily on API data whose state may change at any time.

Let's assume for example that I am testing the login flow of my app by interacting with a log-in form. Because this involves a request to the app's backend, the result of clicking the log-in button may change depending on: network conditions, whether the user is still active, whether the user's username and password are unchanged and so on.

In order to overcome this I though I could add a new product flavour for testing purposes in which network requests are overridden to return predetermined responses. Although this may work, it would seem to add a lot of complication to the app as I'd now have to maintain multiple versions of the same source files.

So my question is, how is this issue usually handled in an Android project? Would the flavour option normally be considered acceptable? Or are there more elegant solutions on can use?

Comment: You can mock what is returned by your model. Let's say I call `login()`, you mock the returned value, like that you can test when the log in is accepted, when the password is wrong, etc